# Emacs clojure: go to definition

Tags: emacs, clojure

I use ergoemacs-mode, clojuremode and autocomplete

Autocomplete works very well. What should I press to go to definition of a function? I get used to Cursive, but I want to use free Emacs and I needed go to definition feature.

Here is my `init.el` file:

```
(global-set-key [f8] 'neotree-toggle)

;; Set bigger fonts
(set-default-font "Ubuntu Mono-16")

(add-hook 'clojure-mode-hook 'turn-on-eldoc-mode)
(setq nrepl-popup-stacktraces nil)
(add-to-list 'same-window-buffer-names "<em>nrepl</em>")


;; General Auto-Complete
(require 'auto-complete-config)
(setq ac-delay 0.0)
(setq ac-quick-help-delay 0.5)
(ac-config-default)

;; ac-nrepl (Auto-complete for the nREPL)
(require 'ac-nrepl)
(add-hook 'cider-mode-hook 'ac-nrepl-setup)
(add-hook 'cider-repl-mode-hook 'ac-nrepl-setup)
(add-to-list 'ac-modes 'cider-mode)
(add-to-list 'ac-modes 'cider-repl-mode)

(add-hook 'clojure-mode-hook 'paredit-mode)
(require 'package)

(add-to-list 'package-archives
  '("melpa-stable" . "http://melpa-stable.milkbox.net/packages/"))

(add-to-list 'package-archives
  '("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/"))

(add-to-list 'package-archives
  '("marmalade" . "http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/"))

;; Initialize all the ELPA packages (what is installed using the packages commands)
(package-initialize)

;;(package-initialize)
(require 'ergoemacs-mode)

(setq ergoemacs-theme nil) ;; Uses Standard Ergoemacs keyboard theme
(setq ergoemacs-keyboard-layout "us") ;; Assumes QWERTY keyboard layout
(ergoemacs-mode 1)

(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/elpa/neotree-20150102.427")
(require 'neotree)
(global-set-key [f8] 'neotree-toggle)

;; Set bigger fonts
(set-default-font "Ubuntu Mono-16")

(add-hook 'clojure-mode-hook 'turn-on-eldoc-mode)
(setq nrepl-popup-stacktraces nil)
(add-to-list 'same-window-buffer-names "<em>nrepl</em>")


;; General Auto-Complete
(require 'auto-complete-config)
(setq ac-delay 0.0)
(setq ac-quick-help-delay 0.5)
(ac-config-default)

;; ac-nrepl (Auto-complete for the nREPL)
(require 'ac-nrepl)
(add-hook 'cider-mode-hook 'ac-nrepl-setup)
(add-hook 'cider-repl-mode-hook 'ac-nrepl-setup)
(add-to-list 'ac-modes 'cider-mode)
(add-to-list 'ac-modes 'cider-repl-mode)

(add-hook 'clojure-mode-hook 'paredit-mode)
(global-set-key [f8] 'neotree-toggle)

;; Set bigger fonts
(set-default-font "Ubuntu Mono-16")

(add-hook 'clojure-mode-hook 'turn-on-eldoc-mode)
(setq nrepl-popup-stacktraces nil)
(add-to-list 'same-window-buffer-names "<em>nrepl</em>")


;; General Auto-Complete
(require 'auto-complete-config)
(setq ac-delay 0.0)
(setq ac-quick-help-delay 0.5)
(ac-config-default)

;; ac-nrepl (Auto-complete for the nREPL)
(require 'ac-nrepl)
(add-hook 'cider-mode-hook 'ac-nrepl-setup)
(add-hook 'cider-repl-mode-hook 'ac-nrepl-setup)
(add-to-list 'ac-modes 'cider-mode)
(add-to-list 'ac-modes 'cider-repl-mode)

(add-hook 'clojure-mode-hook 'paredit-mode)

;; Show parenthesis mode
(show-paren-mode 1)
(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(custom-enabled-themes (quote (whiteboard)))
 '(delete-selection-mode t)
 '(org-CUA-compatible nil)
 '(org-replace-disputed-keys nil)
 '(recentf-mode t)
 '(shift-select-mode nil))
(custom-set-faces
 ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 )
```

Answer (score 14):

I believe the shortcut you're looking for is `M-.`

https://github.com/clojure-emacs/cider#keyboard-shortcuts

Comment: What key should I press for M? Command or Alt don't work. I use ergoemacs.

Comment: you might file report/ask at the ergoemacs-mode https://ergoemacs.github.io/bug-report.html matt answer questions and fix usually in the same day.

Comment: Please also right the name of the function. Shortcuts change, functions don't as much.

Comment: I've found `cider-find-var` useful for this.

Comment: command/shortcut to go back after an `M-.` ?